# emulator in android studio does not run

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, emulation

my emulator on android studio run the first time perfectly then the next time gives me'The emulator process for AVD Pixel_5_API_29 has terminated'.

i tried deleting it and download differnt version,it still makes the same (run one time only)

Comment: try to run`flutter doctor -v` and check if there are any issue. Also you can try creating new emulator device.